# hide browser's scrollbar, but not disable it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how do i hide(not disable it) browser window's scrollbar on my webpage? i have tried  `overflow: hidden;` in css, but it not only hides scrollbar, but also DISABLES mousewheel scrolling (only exception is chrome).  i have also used this method, but it is not perfect [here is the link- method is right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll).  feel free to use javascript, or any other means that can solve the problem. thanks 
p.s i know there are similar topics on this forum but  i could not find right answer.

Comment: You refer to another question, which has several answer providing different solutions for various browsers and even a jQuery plugin for browsers that don't support it at all. Please describe in detail why those answers don't work for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide scroll bar, but still being able to scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Comment: provided answer only worked best if browser scrollbar width was  15px. it was not responsive friendly, besides i wonna use webpage on mobile also. the mentioned jquery plugin only styles scrollbars,  can i hide them?

Comment: Are you aware that that questions has 13 answers, 9 of which got upvotes? You can combine some of them as well. If you have trouble, please be clear on your issue. Don't ask people to go and browser through that entire question to distill an answer for you. It is *your* problem, so *you* will have to show at least some effort.

Comment: i am trying man. but nothin comes out.